# Обработка значения QCheckBox по нажатию на кнопку и запуск внешних программ

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qprocess, qcheckbox

Помогите осуществить проверку состояния `QCheckBox` по нажатию кнопки **`Install`**, 
так чтобы по нажатию на кнопку запустились отмеченные программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 217)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 127);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Chrome = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Chrome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Chrome.setFont(font)
        self.Chrome.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Chrome.setObjectName("Chrome")
        self.Yandex = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Yandex.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Yandex.setFont(font)
        self.Yandex.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Yandex.setObjectName("Yandex")
        self.FireFox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.FireFox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.FireFox.setFont(font)
        self.FireFox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.FireFox.setObjectName("FireFox")
        self.Opera = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Opera.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Opera.setFont(font)
        self.Opera.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Opera.setObjectName("Opera")
        self.OperaGX = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.OperaGX.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.OperaGX.setFont(font)
        self.OperaGX.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.OperaGX.setObjectName("OperaGX")
        self.Edge = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Edge.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Edge.setFont(font)
        self.Edge.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Edge.setObjectName("Edge")
        self.Vivaldi = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Vivaldi.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Vivaldi.setFont(font)
        self.Vivaldi.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Vivaldi.setObjectName("Vivaldi")
        self.uTorrent = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.uTorrent.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.uTorrent.setFont(font)
        self.uTorrent.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.uTorrent.setObjectName("uTorrent")
        self.qBitTorrent = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.qBitTorrent.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.qBitTorrent.setFont(font)
        self.qBitTorrent.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.qBitTorrent.setObjectName("qBitTorrent")
        self.Transmission = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Transmission.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Transmission.setFont(font)
        self.Transmission.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Transmission.setObjectName("Transmission")
        self.LibreOffice = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.LibreOffice.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.LibreOffice.setFont(font)
        self.LibreOffice.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.LibreOffice.setObjectName("LibreOffice")
        self.NotePad = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.NotePad.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.NotePad.setFont(font)
        self.NotePad.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.NotePad.setObjectName("NotePad")
        self.winRAR = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.winRAR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 190, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.winRAR.setFont(font)
        self.winRAR.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.winRAR.setObjectName("winRAR")
        self.Thony = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Thony.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 130, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Thony.setFont(font)
        self.Thony.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Thony.setObjectName("Thony")
        self.Atom = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Atom.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 50, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Atom.setFont(font)
        self.Atom.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Atom.setObjectName("Atom")
        self.Zip = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Zip.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 170, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Zip.setFont(font)
        self.Zip.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Zip.setObjectName("Zip")
        self.MicrosoftOffice = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.MicrosoftOffice.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.MicrosoftOffice.setFont(font)
        self.MicrosoftOffice.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.MicrosoftOffice.setObjectName("MicrosoftOffice")
        self.Gvim = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Gvim.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Gvim.setFont(font)
        self.Gvim.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Gvim.setObjectName("Gvim")
        self.VSCode = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.VSCode.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 150, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.VSCode.setFont(font)
        self.VSCode.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.VSCode.setObjectName("VSCode")
        self.SublimeText = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.SublimeText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 110, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.SublimeText.setFont(font)
        self.SublimeText.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.SublimeText.setObjectName("SublimeText")
        self.Everything = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Everything.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 30, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Everything.setFont(font)
        self.Everything.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Everything.setObjectName("Everything")
        self.Windirstat = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Windirstat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 90, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Windirstat.setFont(font)
        self.Windirstat.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Windirstat.setObjectName("Windirstat")
        self.AnvirTM = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnvirTM.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 190, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.AnvirTM.setFont(font)
        self.AnvirTM.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.AnvirTM.setObjectName("AnvirTM")
        self.InfoCD = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.InfoCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.InfoCD.setFont(font)
        self.InfoCD.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.InfoCD.setObjectName("InfoCD")
        self.LockHunter = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.LockHunter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 50, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.LockHunter.setFont(font)
        self.LockHunter.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.LockHunter.setObjectName("LockHunter")
        self.AIDA64 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.AIDA64.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 170, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.AIDA64.setFont(font)
        self.AIDA64.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.AIDA64.setObjectName("AIDA64")
        self.CDbxp = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.CDbxp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 10, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.CDbxp.setFont(font)
        self.CDbxp.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.CDbxp.setObjectName("CDbxp")
        self.Unlocker = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Unlocker.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Unlocker.setFont(font)
        self.Unlocker.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Unlocker.setObjectName("Unlocker")
        self.MarkCD = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.MarkCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 150, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.MarkCD.setFont(font)
        self.MarkCD.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.MarkCD.setObjectName("MarkCD")
        self.HDTunePro = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.HDTunePro.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.HDTunePro.setFont(font)
        self.HDTunePro.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.HDTunePro.setObjectName("HDTunePro")
        self.CpuZ = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.CpuZ.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.CpuZ.setFont(font)
        self.CpuZ.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.CpuZ.setObjectName("CpuZ")
        self.AIMP = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.AIMP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 90, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.AIMP.setFont(font)
        self.AIMP.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.AIMP.setObjectName("AIMP")
        self.Gimp = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Gimp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 190, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Gimp.setFont(font)
        self.Gimp.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Gimp.setObjectName("Gimp")
        self.KMPlayer = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.KMPlayer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 130, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.KMPlayer.setFont(font)
        self.KMPlayer.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.KMPlayer.setObjectName("KMPlayer")
        self.GpuZ = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.GpuZ.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 50, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.GpuZ.setFont(font)
        self.GpuZ.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.GpuZ.setObjectName("GpuZ")
        self.VLC = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.VLC.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 170, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.VLC.setFont(font)
        self.VLC.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.VLC.setObjectName("VLC")
        self.CoreTemp = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.CoreTemp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 10, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.CoreTemp.setFont(font)
        self.CoreTemp.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.CoreTemp.setObjectName("CoreTemp")
        self.MSIAfterburner = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.MSIAfterburner.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 70, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.MSIAfterburner.setFont(font)
        self.MSIAfterburner.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.MSIAfterburner.setObjectName("MSIAfterburner")
        self.Lightshot = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.Lightshot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 150, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Lightshot.setFont(font)
        self.Lightshot.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.Lightshot.setObjectName("Lightshot")
        self.CyberLink = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.CyberLink.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 110, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.CyberLink.setFont(font)
        self.CyberLink.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.CyberLink.setObjectName("CyberLink")
        self.DriverBooster = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.DriverBooster.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 30, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.DriverBooster.setFont(font)
        self.DriverBooster.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.DriverBooster.setObjectName("DriverBooster")
        self.MiniBin = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.MiniBin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 90, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.MiniBin.setFont(font)
        self.MiniBin.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.MiniBin.setObjectName("MiniBin")
        self.VNCServer = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.VNCServer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 130, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.VNCServer.setFont(font)
        self.VNCServer.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.VNCServer.setObjectName("VNCServer")
        self.DriverHub = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.DriverHub.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 50, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.DriverHub.setFont(font)
        self.DriverHub.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.DriverHub.setObjectName("DriverHub")
        self.XrecodeIII = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.XrecodeIII.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 10, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.XrecodeIII.setFont(font)
        self.XrecodeIII.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.XrecodeIII.setObjectName("XrecodeIII")
        self.EarThumpet = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.EarThumpet.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 70, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.EarThumpet.setFont(font)
        self.EarThumpet.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.EarThumpet.setObjectName("EarThumpet")
        self.__ = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.__.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 150, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.__.setFont(font)
        self.__.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.__.setObjectName("__")
        self.TimeER = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.TimeER.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 110, 96, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.TimeER.setFont(font)
        self.TimeER.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")
        self.TimeER.setObjectName("TimeER")
        self.Development = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Development.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 10, 81, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Development.setFont(font)
        self.Development.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(124, 252, 0);")
        self.Development.setObjectName("Development")
        self.Libraries = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Libraries.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 40, 61, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Libraries.setFont(font)
        self.Libraries.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(124, 252, 0);")
        self.Libraries.setObjectName("Libraries")
        self.View = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.View.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 70, 31, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.View.setFont(font)
        self.View.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(124, 252, 0);")
        self.View.setObjectName("View")
        self.Install = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Install.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 190, 41, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.Install.setFont(font)
        self.Install.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 215, 0);")
        self.Install.setObjectName("Install")
        self.SPforPC = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SPforPC.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 160, 51, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.SPforPC.setFont(font)
        self.SPforPC.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(240, 230, 140);")
        self.SPforPC.setObjectName("SPforPC")
        self.SPforNoteBook = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SPforNoteBook.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 130, 91, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setItalic(True)
        self.SPforNoteBook.setFont(font)
        self.SPforNoteBook.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(240, 230, 140);")
        self.SPforNoteBook.setObjectName("SPforNoteBook")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Chrome.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Chrome"))
        self.Yandex.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yandex"))
        self.FireFox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FireFox"))
        self.Opera.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Opera"))
        self.OperaGX.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OperaGX"))
        self.Edge.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edge"))
        self.Vivaldi.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Vivaldi"))
        self.uTorrent.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "uTorrent"))
        self.qBitTorrent.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "qBitTorrent"))
        self.Transmission.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Transmission"))
        self.LibreOffice.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LibreOffice"))
        self.NotePad.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NotePad++"))
        self.winRAR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "winRAR"))
        self.Thony.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Thony"))
        self.Atom.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Atom"))
        self.Zip.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7zip"))
        self.MicrosoftOffice.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MicrosoftOffce"))
        self.Gvim.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Gvim"))
        self.VSCode.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "VSCode"))
        self.SublimeText.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SublimeText"))
        self.Everything.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Everything"))
        self.Windirstat.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Windirstat"))
        self.AnvirTM.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AnvirTM"))
        self.InfoCD.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "InfoCD"))
        self.LockHunter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LockHunter"))
        self.AIDA64.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AIDA64"))
        self.CDbxp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CDbxp"))
        self.Unlocker.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Unlocker"))
        self.MarkCD.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MarkCD"))
        self.HDTunePro.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "HDTunePro"))
        self.CpuZ.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CpuZ"))
        self.AIMP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AIMP"))
        self.Gimp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Gimp"))
        self.KMPlayer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "KMPlayer"))
        self.GpuZ.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GpuZ"))
        self.VLC.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "VLC"))
        self.CoreTemp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CoreTemp"))
        self.MSIAfterburner.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MSIAfterburner"))
        self.Lightshot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lightshot"))
        self.CyberLink.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CyberLink"))
        self.DriverBooster.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DriverBooster"))
        self.MiniBin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MiniBin"))
        self.VNCServer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "VNCServer"))
        self.DriverHub.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DriverHub"))
        self.XrecodeIII.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Xrecode III"))
        self.EarThumpet.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "EarTrumpet"))
        self.__.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FileConverter"))
        self.TimeER.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TimeER"))
        self.Development.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Development"))
        self.Libraries.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Libraries"))
        self.View.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.Install.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Install"))
        self.SPforPC.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SP for PC"))
        self.SPforNoteBook.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SP for NoteBook"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, ваша форма занимает много места и вы не используете менеджеры компоновки, поэтому я ее упростил.

Класс [**QProcess**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) используется для запуска внешних программ и взаимодействия с ними.

Попробуйте мое предложение, но над ним надо будет еще поработать.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):            # , Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.checkBoxes = {
            'Chrome': '', 'Yandex': '', 'FireFox': '',
            'Opera': '', 'OperaGX': '', 'Edge': '',
            'Vivaldi': '', 'uTorrent': '', 'qBitTorrent': '',
            'Transmission': '', 'LibreOffice': '', 'NotePad++': 'Notepad.exe',
# -------------------------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^
            'winRAR': '', 'Thony': '', 'Atom': '',
            '7zip': '', 'MicrosoftOffce': '', 'Gvim': '',
            'VSCode': '', 'SublimeText': '', 'Everything': '',
            'Windirstat': '', 'AnvirTM': '', 'InfoCD': '',
            'LockHunter': '', 'AIDA64': '', 'CDbxp': '',
            'Unlocker': '', 'MarkCD': '', 'HDTunePro': '',
            'CpuZ': '', 'AIMP': '', 'Gimp': '',
            'KMPlayer': '', 'GpuZ': '', 'VLC': '',
            'CoreTemp': '', 'MSIAfterburner': '', 'Lightshot': '',
            'CyberLink': '', 'DriverBooster': '', 'MiniBin': '',
            'VNCServer': '', 'DriverHub': '', 'Xrecode III': '',
            'EarTrumpet': '', 'FileConverter': '', 'TimeER': '',
            'Калькулятор': 'calc.exe',
# ------------------------> ^^^^^^^^
        }
        
        many_cb = len(self.checkBoxes)                     
        column = 5 
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.check_boxes = []

        for step, name in enumerate(self.checkBoxes):
            cb = QCheckBox(name, objectName=name.lower())
            cb.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                             "color: rgb(85, 255, 127);")            
            row = step // column
            col = step % column
            layout.addWidget(cb, row, col)  
            self.check_boxes.append(cb)

        self.frame = QFrame()   
        self.Development = QPushButton('Development')
        self.Development.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                       "color: rgb(124, 252, 0);")
        self.Libraries = QPushButton('Libraries')
        self.Libraries.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                     "color: rgb(124, 252, 0);")
        self.View = QPushButton('View')
        self.View.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(124, 252, 0);")
        self.Install = QPushButton('Install')
        self.Install.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "color: rgb(255, 215, 0);")
        self.SPforPC = QPushButton('SPforPC')
        self.SPforPC.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "color: rgb(240, 230, 140);")
        self.SPforNoteBook = QPushButton('SPforNoteBook')
        self.SPforNoteBook.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                         "color: rgb(240, 230, 140);")
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        layoutV.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.Development) 
        layoutV.addWidget(self.Libraries)         
        layoutV.addWidget(self.View) 
        layoutV.addStretch(1)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.SPforNoteBook) 
        layoutV.addWidget(self.SPforPC)        
        layoutV.addWidget(self.Install) 
        
        layout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, column, row+1, 1)
        
        self.Install.clicked.connect(self.start_installation)  
        
    def start_installation(self):
        self.process = []
        for box in self.check_boxes:
           if box.isChecked():
               name_exe = self.checkBoxes.get(box.text())
               #print(f'{box.text()} -- {name_exe}') 
               
               if name_exe:
                   process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
                   self.process.append(process)
                   
                   self.process[-1].stateChanged.connect(
                       lambda state, name=name_exe: self.new_state(state, name)) 
                   
                   self.process[-1].start(name_exe) 
               
    def new_state(self, newState, name):
        if newState == 1:
            text = f"\nПроцесс запускается, но программа {name} еще не запущена."
        elif newState == 2:
            text = f"Процесс запущен и программа {name} готова к работе."
        elif newState == 0:
            text = f"Процесс {name} не запущен."
        print(f'{text}') #
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ИванГрозный что не так?

Comment: спасибо большое, что упростили мой код))))
а можно как-то сделать чтобы выбранные файлы открывались по очереди (по одному) ?

Comment: @ИванГрозный  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать список `QCheckBox` и, пробежавшись по нему, запускать выбранные программы, словарь вида `QCheckBox: str`:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    # тут ваш код
    self.checkBoxes = [self.Lightshot, self.CoreTemp, ...]
    self.checkBox_CMD = {
        self.Lightshot: 'lightshot.exe',
        self.CoreTemp: 'coretemp.exe',
        ...
    }
    self.Install.clicked.connect(self.start_installation)  # если нажали кнопку - запускаем установку

def start_installation(self):
    for box in self.checkBoxes:
       if box.isChecked():
           os.system(self.checkBox_CMD[box])
```

Comment: программа не запускается, просто закрывается без всяких ошибок

Comment: как вы ёё запускаете ? двойным кликом или через среду разработки ? @ИванГрозный

Comment: обоими способами

Comment: @ИванГрозный исправил код (название функции не то написал: `__init__` и `setupUi` перепутал). попробуйте теперь.

Comment: всё равно код не запускается

Comment: @ИванГрозный вы дополнили список и словарь ? или хотя бы убрали `...` ?

Comment: да, убрал и дополнил

Comment: если вы не против, давайте продолжим обсуждение в Телеграмме или на какой то другой площадки для удобства. )))
вот мой телеграмм https://t.me/Zhenya14